# Is there a JS library to add HTML 5 features to browsers, which don't support them?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to use `autofocus="autofocus"` in my code, but since some browsers don't support this yet, I was thinking of adding some JS code, which would search for an element with such a tag, and focus it with JS. But since this seems to be a common requirement, I wonder if there are any ready libraries, which can take care of at least some HTML5 annoyances with older browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct answer would be not quite. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) 2.0 (including html5shim) gives us semantic elements of html5 (actually the html5shim does that) and great feature detection which you can use for graceful js fallback.

In you case It would be using jQuery .focus() with something like:

```
      if (!Modernizr.autofocus){
        $('input[autofocus=""]').focus();
  }
```

more examples [here](http://blog.mirthlab.com/2010/01/08/using-modernizr-to-implement-missing-html5-features-in-browsers/)

Answer (score 2):

If older browsers don't support certain advanced features, then I would say follow [progressive enhancement](http://progressive%20enhancement) and **don't worry about it**.  So long as the core functionality of your site—ordering products, or whatever—works across the board, then don't be afraid to add in shiny html5 features for the benefit of your users with good browsers.

Putting in clunky/third-party code to force IE6 and 7 to behave in a civilized manner will potentially be a lot of work for you, will be prone to bugs, and won't even give you too much of a payoff since the folks using IE6 probably won't be looking over the shoulders of Chrome users to see a nicer version of your site there.

Here are the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/progressive-enhancement-20) (from a jQuery conference) that really drove this home for me.

Answer (score 0):

Users of libraries like jQuery say that they implement such a features.
I don’t recommend it anyway, try to code the minimum functions you need by yourself.

Take also a look at http://www.modernizr.com/.

Comment: Modernizr doesn't *implement* the missing features, it just does feature detection.

Comment: Thanks for the info @duri, Actually I never took a look in it.

Answer (score 0):

The role of [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (previously mentioned) is to do feature detection, to determine what HTML 5 features are available.  Modernizr doesn't automatically make unavailable HTML 5 features available, but it does make it possible for you to conditionally load scripts (commonly referred to as polyfills) to add those features.  In the case of `autofocus`, the [html5support](https://github.com/amiel/html5support) library should provide what you need, and you can use Modernizr's conditional loading to only load it if needed.